# Using diferent log4j2.xml per maven profile

Tags: spring-boot, maven, configuration, log4j

Usng maven and springbooot. I'd like to use diferent file configurations (log4j2.xml, application.properties) per enviroment (dev, cert). I have two profiles created on my pom.xml file, also I have two folder into src/main/resources with each files configurations (dev and cert). I'd like to include these files depending on the profile I'm using. I have others files in the directory, so I dont want to use the way to create two routes and duplicate files, I'd like just include everything in src/main/resources and the files in the directory dev or cert.

[image]

I tried to use :

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingIncludes>src/main/resources/{resources.directory}</packagingIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But I'm getting

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:repackage
> (default) on project NProWebApp: Execution default of goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:repackage
> failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]

EDIT :
Adding profiles in maven :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>cert</id>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with Maven. Just package all the files together and create spring configuration files of the format application-{profile}.properties.  Then, in that file define your logging configuration location using logging.config=log4j2-{profile}.xml where {profile} is the profile name for the current file.

Note that in yml you can also put multiple profile configurations in a single application.yml file.

Comment: Hi, sound good your solution, but when I created the war, it contain both application.properties (dev and cert), and both log4j.xml, I think something is missing in order to say the maven what files take, am I right? I'm going to edit the question in order to add info about the profiles